# Why are there multiple ApplicationHost.config files?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-express, applicationhost

I've found ApplicationHost.config in the following directories:

1. `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`
2. `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\IISExpress\config`
3. `C:\MyApp1\.vs\App1\config`

Why are there multiple ApplicationHost.config files and what are they used for?

If I want to change the bindings just for my local ASP.NET app running in Visual Studio, which file do I edit?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html# and https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/iis.html#

Answer (score 0):

> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\ApplicationHost.config

This ApplicationHost.config is the root file of the configuration system when you are using IIS 7 and above. It includes definitions of all sites, applications, virtual directories and application pools, as well as global defaults for the web server settings. More information you can refer to this link: [Introduction to ApplicationHost.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig).

> C:\Users\david\My Documents\IISExpress\config\ApplicationHost.config

IIS Express and IIS use the ApplicationHost.config file, which specifies global settings for sites, application pools, handlers, etc. IIS Express uses a default, user-specific ApplicationHost.config file to allow many users to share the same computer without interfering with other user's settings. This file is located in the %userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config folder or %userprofile%\My Documents\IISExpress\config folder, depending on your OS.

> C:\MyApp1.vs\App1\config\ApplicationHost.config

The use of this ApplicationHost.config file is the same as above, but this file will only exist when creating an ASP.NET Web application project.

So what you should edit is the ApplicationHost.config file in the `C:\MyApp1\.vs\App1\config` path.

Comment: Which one wins out of `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\ApplicationHost.config` and `C:\Users\david\My Documents\IISExpress\config\ApplicationHost.config?

Comment: You can't compare like this, one is in iis, the other is in iis express.

Comment: According to the first link in @Lex Li's comment under my question:
"In older Visual Studio releases (such as 2012/2013), a global IIS Express configuration file can be found at %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config or %userprofile%\my documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config."

"When you create a new web project in Visual Studio 2015/2017, the IDE adds a custom IIS Express configuration file to the project folder at ($SolutionDir)\.vs\config\applicationHost.config."

It seems as though the IISExpress one isn't used anymore since VS is now past v2013.

Comment: [IIS Express](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview) is built into visual studio, It has nothing to do with the version of visual studio.

Comment: When I say "the IISExpress one", I'm talking about the `%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config`

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. If you are referring to iisexpress under documents, then that is the one I am talking about.

Comment: If you are running an app in VS which uses IIS Express, does it use `C:\MyApp1.vs\App1\config` or `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\IISExpress\config`? Your answer is vague on this. It just says "to allow many users to share the same computer without interfering with other user's settings", and then for `C:\MyApp1.vs\App1\config\ApplicationHost.config` you say "will only exist when creating an ASP.NET Web application project.".

Comment: If you are running an app in VS which uses IIS Express, it actually first creates a copy of the config located at `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\IISExpress\config` and puts it under `{Solution}\.vs\{Project}\config\applicationhost.config`. It then just refers to `{Solution}\.vs\{Project}\config\applicationhost.config` going forward. So, if you wanted to make a change you could do it directly on the `{Solution}\.vs\{Project}\config\applicationhost.config` and it will just apply to that solution/project.